# Is there anything wrong with closing old questions as dupes?

Tags: discussion

Recently I voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241133/how-can-i-create-lists-from-a-list-of-strings?lq=1) as exact dupe of [this one I've answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24937068/create-new-lists-from-elements-of-a-list?lq=1).  Because I have gold badge in python tag, this action was effective immediately.

Some minutes later the action has been reversed by another user also with gold badge in python tag, when I asked for explanation he says that an older question can not be a duplicate of newer question.  But I will usually cast a close vote because of content, irrespective of dates.

Should we try to avoid to close older questions as duplicates of newer ones, all other things being equal?  Should we check the dates and close the newer question, or doesn't it matter?

Comment: @AndreSilva Age is irrelevant. The lower quality post should be closed as a duplicate of the higher quality post, regardless of age.  That said, it may be that he chose the wrong canonical question by that metric as well (although this is not my area of expertise).

Comment: @Servy, I partially agree. I agree that quality should come first, but age should be considered (disagree that is irrelevant). If a new post is only a little bit better than the oldest one, then the latter should be kept opened (for its originality).

Comment: @AndreSilva Why?  What possible value is there in even considering it?

Comment: @AndreSilva There are even some cases where I have seen that a question is an exact dupe, but the newer one has much better answers because of a bugfix, new tool or a new feature in the language which was not possible at the time of the old question.  Many old question contain outdated answers!

Comment: both questions could be left alone.. Sometimes it can be good to have some duplicated... i.e. different searches and different ways of describing the same problem results in more users finding it on google / other searches... Even better if they link to each other.

Comment: @Robbo_UK That's the point of closing as a duplicate, to redirect users who find the differently-worded question via Google, etc., to the best question & answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Three users voted to reopen the question, one of which also wields the mjolnir.  Presumably they felt that the question is not a duplicate.  You could comment on the post to ask them why they felt the post wasn't a duplicate if you do not understand how they differ.

The other possibility, in looking at the questions more closely, is that they may have felt that you closed the wrong question, and that you had closed the higher quality post as a duplicate of a lower quality post, and should have done the reverse.

Comment: I didn't think there is any difference in the quality of the posts in this case, they are virtually identical.  The reopener did not choose to close the other way, either, they are now both open again.

Comment: @wim Which is why I suggested you ask them for their reasoning.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know who we are talking about, there does not seem to be any avenue for communication between closers and reopeners

Comment: @wim Just look at the revision history and you can see exactly who did what, when.

Comment: Not saying this is the case as I don't know: But maybe they didn't like that you closed the older one with them being pretty much the same quality wise (if they agree with you on that statement) when you answered the newer one. They may have seen it as a conflict of interest, @wim. But of course this is just a guess at what happened, and why they reopened. (May explain the downvote as well.)

Comment: You might be correct.  In this case I really don't care which is closed for which, it's just how my workflow went, I would happily close the other aswell.

Comment: As the wielder, and as I explained in the comments to that post (which wim and I should remove now), it's not that we thought it wasn't a duplicate-- it's that that wasn't a great dup target.  It was basically the same answer (and that the target answer was by wim didn't go unnoticed), but later.  Better answers can be targets even if they're more recent, of course -- some of us who work the Python tag are trying to establish [a canon](http://sopython.com/canon/), and self-answering to that end -- but if we get into the habit of dup-closing *forward* equivalent answers, we'll never stop.

Comment: @DSM In that case, why not close the newer as dupe rather than leaving both open?  What value does it add to the site to re-open the dupe, and for that matter why leave a downvote on the accepted answer (assuming it was you also)?  I can see where you're coming from, but having one more thing to check when VTC duplicate is a bit annoying if there is no obvious value in preserving some chronological ordering for dupes.

Comment: @wim we figured you'd bring it to meta... I've given an answer about the reasoning - but in short, we're trying to find a dupe to close them all to - it's not about their answer, or their answer - we just need a good resource - that's what SO is for

Answer (score 17):

As the accepted answerer of [How can I create lists from a list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241133/how-can-i-create-lists-from-a-list-of-strings) and one of the active members of the Python tag, I will try and outline what happened.

A question had been closed as a duplicate to the question I replied to. Several minutes later, that same question had been "hammered" as a duplicate to a question the OP had an accepted answer on -- this to me seemed fairly "self-indulgent".

We talked about it in the [Python room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) - I had a bit of rant really, as I was annoyed about it (bad day - we all get those).

I made it clear I wasn't going to start a hammer war - I could have immediately re-opened and re-closed, but that could potentially make me a hypocrite (and myself seem self-indulgent).

The Python community (those that participate in chat (obviously we don't speak for *everyone* but we're pretty much 24/7 and making sure stuff doesn't slip through the net where we can), and try to make things easier all-around for everyone) voted on the quality of the answers, not the age.

If the dupe target had better answers, a better structured question and title, I couldn't have cared less to be honest. It just wasn't... we need the best canonical dupes we can find for visitors and that wasn't it (at least in our opinion).

wim - If you wish to help in finding it, you're more than welcome - it's bound to have been asked many times... (and I'm sure answered in some terrifying ways!)